# Setting up an PHP+MySQL website on Google Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I chose to put my website on Google Cloud but I have no idea how to achieve that. I have a little experience in Linux and no experience at all by setting up any hosting for a website.

Questions here are:

Is that possible to set up a website if it is written in PHP+MySQL (and, of course, Javascript) ?

If yes:

How? How does it work?

Comment: Google cloud should not be the first place you go to when learning how to setup a website. Using free webhosting services will make your transition easier. Visit Lynda.com for resources on web development (you'll have to pay for it) or you can google "how to make a website" or "how to make/host my first website".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Google App Engine:

PHP runtime is currently in limited preview. (so not everything is working as expected) And instead of using MySQL, you have to use CloudSQL. For details please see here: 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/

You don't need any Linux experience for using GAE, but you will need to read through the documentations.

Javascript is client side program so it doesn't matter with the server.

Comment: Is that the same for Amazon EC2? Is that possible to use Amazon to achieve my purpose?

Comment: @Hypn0tizeR Amazon EC2 is a completely different story. Amazon EC2 is basically like a virtual computer, where you have to run your own or any of the already prepared OS image (e.g. Linux), and do all the server setup work manually and remotely. (Hence the term: Infrastructure As A Service).  

Where GAE is Platform As A Service (does not require you any server administration tasks)

As said by Fahad above, it seems better off you just use a regular hosting if you simply need PHP + MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Due to query latency it might be impossible to run a standard not cloud optimized PHP/python/etc. CMS in the cloud. My current experience is that a standard CMS makes up to 100 queries to render a page accounting for several seconds delay. That only works on a local DB fast enough.